Type3 compensator with OPA
I'm about to simulate a voltage_mode buck converter. To stabilize this converter, I use a type 3 compensator. The configuration of that compensator is given below, with the values of the first pole with the following specifications: I'm wondering why the first pole is at 200uHz and I want to know how I could control the first pole of the compensator. Besides the first pole, the simulation results of fp2/fp3/fz1/fz2 are well matched with my calculation.
Thanks advanced!
Specifications:
The switching frequency is at 1MHz.
The output voltage from the power stage is 1.8V.
The double poles are at 23.2kHz
The zero of the cout&Resr is at 1.6MHz
I placed the first zero at 1kHz/second zero at 36kHz/second pole at 2.4MHz/third pole at 4MHz.
The pode plot and the parameter of the OPAMP that I have simulated are shown below:




In a compensator like type 1, 2 or 3, there is a pole at the origin: when $s=0$, the gain is theoretically infinite. It is an integrator. In reality, this gain is bounded by the open-loop gain of the active element you have used. Then, the op-amp itself hosts a low-frequency pole (circa 30 Hz but higher also for wide GBW types) and another one at crossover. You should try to characterize the op-amp model you have used. Also, did you give a try at my automated templates?

Thanks for your response. I'm trying your automated templates, but there are some programming syntaxes I haven't fixed.  Additionally, I have tried modifying the parameters of the OPAMP which build in the simplis, the GBW=70MHz and the open loop gain=10k, Is the low-frequency pole supposed to be '70M/10k=7K'?

Ni hao, I am surprised with the components values you have, especially with a supposedly-high crossover frequency: the 8.8-µF and 18 ohms make no sense to me. Please let me know where you wanted to place the poles and zeroes and I can give it a try.

I could use your automated templates already. It's really useful! Before I compensated the circuit, I tested the open loop gain of the buck converter, There is a double pole at 23.2k and one zero at 1.6MHz. I want to put the cross-frequency in the range of (fc/5 - fc/10), so I set fc at 150kHz.Besides the original pole, I want to place the other two poles at 2.4MHz and 4MHz, the zero at 1k and 36k. Is there something wrong with the poles and zeroes placement or do I have the wrong calculation of the components values?

If this is for a voltage-mode buck, then place one zero at the resonance and another one below, maybe 10 kHz or so. You will have to check how it goes in DCM as phase margin can suffer. If this is a sync-rectified buck, no issue, leave the double zero at resonance. Then a second pole should cancel the ESR but if too high, set one pole at half the switching frequency and adjust the second to get the right phase margin. Do this first with a perfect op-amp and check the response is ok and then, replace the op-amp with a realistic model.

Thanks for your suggestions. I'll try to compensate for these points. There is another problem with my compensation. I know that there is a pole at the origin. But in reality, the op-amp itself hosts a low-frequency pole. Does it mean the dominant pole of the ideal opamp dominates the first pole of this compensator? If the ideal opamp does dominate the first pole, then I hope to know if is there any solution that could fix this problem.

You have negative feedback around your op-amp, right? So the dominant pole of the amplifier will move out to a higher frequency where it shouldn't interfere with the low-frequency pole.  You still eventually have to take the frequency response of the op-amp into account to be sure it doesn't degrade your phase margin, but your pole at origen is a good thing, it drives the DC error to (ideally) zero.

I realized that the dominant pole of the opamp would move out to a higher frequency if I had negative feedback and the pole at the origin could drive the DC error to be ideally zero. The issue I was still confused about was how I could have the cross-frequency at 150kHz. Due to this compensator, there are three cross-frequency at 100Hz/15kHz/37Hz separately because the low-frequency pole at 200uHz has pulled down the most gain of the opamp.
